# Colors in zsh completion _arguments

Tags: zsh

I'm trying to find an example of an `_arguments` directive in a zsh completion script that prints certain arguments using colors.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/zsh#Colors

So far whatever I tried ended up escape characters shown on the screen instead of turning into colors.

Answer (score 0):

abit late but still,
I found that the following code will color highlight the completion results.
useful for dynamically generated completions.

```
#compdef colorgrep
local -a colors
    colors="$( _call_program 'colgrep' grep --help 2>/dev/null |\
      awk -vtick="'" -F' ' "BEGIN { OFS=\"\"; red=\"\033[31m\" ;white=\"\033[37m\"; };
      /^\s+-/ {
          gsub(/[:\`\]\[]|tick|the\s/,\"\",\$0);
          gsub(/\s\s/,\"\",\$0);
          split(\$1,option,/[=,]/);
          gsub(\$1,\"\",\$0);
          gsub(\$2,\"\",\$0);
          \$0=red\$0white;
          printf \"%s[%s]:%s:\n\",option[1],\$0,option[2] }" )"
      #convert to array
      colors=("${(f)colors}")
_arguments $colors
```